# Updating records on cousin object using SF Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

We have an app that is made up of almost entirely custom objects. Creating a smooth workflow for our users is vital for this app. I'm new to apex, but familiar with basic code writing.

Here are the relationships between the objects: (--< = 1 to many, M/D = Master/Detail)

Object_a --< Object_b --M/D--< Object_c;
Object_a --M/D--< Object_d

When a user populates a date field on Object_c and saves, we'd like a date field on all related records on Object_d (i.e. all Object_d's records for that specific Object_a record) to be updated with the same value.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a trigger on insert / update of `Object_c` as workflow rules can't fire on update of multiple objects and rollup summary fields won't help (master-details aren't set everywhere).

Before you deep dive into coding please consider what should happen if you have more than 1 `Object__c` modified at the same time (with Data Loader for example, through integration with some external system or other piece of code). If you have 2 records that both are related to same `Object_A` and one has "today" while other has "today + 7", which value should "win"?

---

One way of solving it would be to start with a map of `Object_A` Ids and date values to set. The way I'll be building the map means I'll keep overwriting the values on case of duplicate id which is not what you might need (select later of the dates maybe?).

```
Map<Id, Date> datesToSet = new Map<Id, Date>(); // you could make it Map<Id, Object_C__c> too, principle would be similar

for(Object_C__c c : [SELECT Id, Date_Field__c, Object_B__r.Object_A__c FROM Object_C__c WHERE Id IN :trigger.new AND Object_B__r.Object_A__c != null]){
    datesToSet.put(c.dObject_B__r.Object_A__c, c.Date_Field__c);
}

System.debug(datesToSet);
```

Now we have map of unique A ids and values we should apply to all their child D records.

```
List<Object_D__c> childsToUpdate = [SELECT Id, Some_Other_Date_Field__c, Object_A__c FROM Object_D__c WHERE Object_A__c IN :datesToSet.keyset()];

System.debug('BEFORE: ' + childsToUpdate);
for(Object_D__c d : childsToUpdate){
    d.Some_Other_Date_Field__c = datesToSet.get(d.Object_A__c);
}
System.debug('AFTER: ' + childsToUpdate);
update childsToUpdate;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Theoretically, the relationships between A, B, and C are all one to many. The way our system is setup, however, it is a one to one to one. If fact, some time in the future, I need to come up with a way of preventing many records from being created on B & C.

Comment: Put unique text(18) field on B & C and have a workflow that fills it with value of A Id (and B Id respectively) :) You'll have to fill it in for existing data though.